# How to convert apache log time to activerecord :datetime

Tags: ruby, apache, datetime, activerecord

I'd like to save apache logs to MySQL via ActiveRecord. In the apache log, the default time string is like:

```
[13/Aug/2008:00:50:49 -0700]
```

How can I convert it to a ActiveRecord `:datetime` type? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
apache_time = "[13/Aug/2008:00:50:49 -0700]"
d = DateTime.strptime( apache_time, "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z]")
```

The format string is documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.src/M000298.html

Comment: This code works in Python if you do `from datetime import datetime as DateTime`, and also use `%z` instead of `%Z` in the format string ;) BTW, I was actually googling for the format string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get `DateTime` to parse your string after removing the colon between the year and hour:

```
# given apache_time = "[13/Aug/2008:00:50:49 -0700]"
stamp = apache_time.sub %r[(/\d{4}):(\d{2})], '\1 \2'
datetime = DateTime.parse stamp   # returns DateTime representing "2008-08-13T00:50:49-07:00"
```